# Recover deleted files on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, files, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I just rm -rf'ed a folder with a few files I need. Yes I know I should've had a backup, but it's just a Pi. It's designed to be played around with!

Is there *anything* I can do to recover that folder? Would the files be cached somewhere? Can you recommend any Linux file recovery programs?

I don't want to boot into the SD again as it might write over the data :(

Help!

EXT4 filesystem.

Comment: What filesystem would the SD have?